# Getting the names of documents in Firestore Collection to show up as options in Select Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make an app that will allow users to register for a tournament, where the tournament options are pulled from a firestore collection and their name displayed in a dropdown select. 
Currently I can see how many tournaments are available in the drop-down, but they just say undefined instead of the name.
If it helps for this form I only care about the name of the tournament, I don't need all the other attributes that are being mapped.
[Image Showing Drop Down When Two Items Are In The Database Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzIPz.png)
[Image Showing How The Firestore DB is set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhTn5.png)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let tournaments = this.db
      .collection("tournaments")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        tournaments = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        this.setState({ tournaments });
        this.tournamentChoices();
      });
  }

  tournamentChoices() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.tournaments.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
        txt = document.createTextNode(this.state.tournaments[i].name);
      option.appendChild(txt);
      option.setAttribute("value", this.state.tournaments[i].name);
      select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
    }
  }
```

```
  <FormGroup>
    <Input type="select" id="select" onChange={this.handleTournament}>
        <option value="default">Select Tournament</option>
    </Input>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: type `select` on input? Can you show me what your component looks like with the undefined fields? Should be using `<select>` with `<option>` children for dropdown selections.

Comment: I'm using React-Strap, that's why the input tags are like that. I've edited my post to show the dropdown.

Comment: Oh, Looks like you are missing setAttribute `text`

Comment: Doesn't look like setting the text attribute changed anything.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The problem was with how I was storing tournaments when adding to the db from my app. I had it set up incorrectly so tournaments were being nested inside a tournament of the same name without any other attributes.
Thanks for the help.

```
this.db.collection('tournaments').doc(this.state.name).set(
            tournament //originally this was {tournament} so was passing in an object not the values
        );
    };
```